# Styling php code with more than one html attribute is not working

Tags: php, html, css

I am using Apache with CentOS 6 and have a problem styling my PHP code. Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Time</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3 style="font-family:Cursive, color: green, font-size:32px">
            <?php
                $tt = date("h:i A");

                echo $tt;
            ?>
        </h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

So I use PHP to display the time, and inline CSS to style it. The problem is that only the first CSS attribute is working (Once executed, the time is in cursive, but it's not green and not 32px big).

What do I do in order to get the other attributes working? Why is the first attribute only being executed?

Comment: It should be seperated by `;`, not `,`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using `;` instead of `,`.

You can test with this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/62qbznpq/).

Answer (score 3):

Your CSS is invalid. Use a semicolon `;` between styles:

```
<h3 style="font-family: Cursive; color: green; font-size: 32px">
```